# Expresiones condicionales para un if

Tags: javascript, condiciones, script, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesitaría ayuda ya que estoy empezando con **APPS SCRIPT** y no logro averiguar como poner las expresiones condicionales para que dependiendo de la hora se meta en un `IF` o en otro.

Lo tengo asi:

```
if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("V5!D"+ contador).getValue()!=" - "){
    if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("V5!D"+ contador).getValue()=="8*"){    
        var cell = sheet.getRange("E" + contadorlu);
        var value = Math.floor((Math.random()*(rango_max - rango_min)) + rango_min);         
        cell.setValue(value);   
     } 
}
```

En esta expresión necesitaria que se metiese en ese IF al verificar que empieza por 8 y por 9.

```
if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("V5!D"+ contador).getValue()=="8*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de

```
if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("V5!D"+ contador).getValue()=="8*")
```

podrías usar

```
const value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("V5!D"+ contador).getValue();
if(value.slice(0,1) === "8" || value.slice(0,1) === "9")
```

- `String.prototype.slice` extrae un parte de una cadena de texto con base en los índices de inicio y fin
- `||` operador O lógico

o bien

```
const value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("V5!D"+ contador).getValue();
if(/^8|9/.test(value))
```

- `/^8|9/`es una expresión regular
- `RegEx.prototype.test` evalua si la cadena de texto coincide con la expresión regular.

---

Google Apps Script usa JavaScript como lenguaje de programación con algunas limitaciones con respecto lo que se puede hacer en una navegador web y otras plataformas como Node.js.

En primer lugar, evita los "oneliner" (hacer muchas cosas en una sóla línea de código) ya que esto dificulta la lectura del código y en su momento su depuración.

Aprende acerca de los tipos de datos y objetos de JavaScript. En este caso en particular `string` (primitivo) y `String` (objeto) son esenciales. También `RegEx` (expresiones regulares) te sería de mucha utilidad.

Para hacer tu código eficiente evita hacer llamadas a métodos de los servicios de Google Apps Script en bucles debido a que son lentos. Para ello aprende el manejo de Arrays y a realizar operaciones por lotes.

Comment: Muchas gracias Ruben, por supuesto los tendré en cuenta tus consejos.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque desconozco el lenguaje que mencionas hay ciertas cosas que yo intentaría hacer independientemente del lenguaje.

No se si lo que haces esta dentro de un bucle for, lo digo por el contador, de esta manera simplemente evaluaría el valor de esa variable y ejecutaría el código necesario.

Comment: Si, exacto, estaría metido en un for que lo que hace es recorrer a todos los trabajadores de una empresa. Despues con este código me compararía con el signo - si esta libre o tiene un horario y finalmente quiero que me compare si entra a las 8:00 y si entra a las 9:00, ahí es donde no se como lograr que me compare.

Comment: if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("V5!D"+ contador).getValue()=="8*,9*")

Comment: Evalua contador  y ejecuta el codigo adecuado
si contador = 8 
ejecuta este codigo 

si contador == 9
ejecuta este otro codigo

Comment: Si, la idea es que me coja la comparacion y que me busque que empiece por 8 y que empiece por 9 la condicion ya que el la celda en la que compara seria de mayor tamaño y puede cambiar aun entrando a las 8. lo compararia con 8:00 - 16:00 y con 9:00 - 17:00